# I get the error "Not Implemented GET to /login.html not supported." only when redirecting from another page

Tags: php, html, ssl

I've searched and I cannot find why this problem is happening. I'm fairly certain it has something to do with my recent addition of SSL to the site I'm making.

When I load the page directly (through entering the URL), it works fine, however, when it is redirected from another page, using `window.location.href = "login.html";`, it gives me the error, specifically:

```
Not Implemented

GET to /login.html not supported.
```

login.html, the page the returns the error is just a simple form with username and password using the post method. When I refresh the page, it works fine.

The error number is 501.

This only happens when I connect with https:// rather than http://

UPDATE: I've found some more information. When I try and load the page in IE (as opposed to Chrome), it doesn't load at all. It gives me a `HTTP 501/HTTP 505` error.

Comment: I'm running the server. It's a WAMP server.